# New host does not show up on Nagios Core Web Interface

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, monitoring, nagios

I've been having a few problems with my Nagios Core server, every time I add a host to it won't show up on the web interface although it is being monitored and the system notifies when the host goes up or down.

I've checked the permissions, the config files, and the syntax of the host file but everything seems to be fine, any idea on what could I be missing.

Comment: Can you post the config for this host and the user you are logged into the web application with?

Comment: Sure, [this](https://pastebin.com/ECwePgx0) is the nagios.cfg file anf [this](https://pastebin.com/b7h2nsAN) is the cgi.cfg, the user I'm using is adminnagios

Comment: Thanks but where is your config that defines this host? Have you got a config file in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/Hosts`?

Comment: The config files are arranged in a series of folders within /usr/local/nagios/etc/Hosts, and if I run nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg the systems sees them all. As far as how the hosts are declared, it's either one of the host definitions in [this](https://pastebin.com/3AEXkqrM) config file depending on the address that is used to access them.

Comment: So what do you see when you click Hosts in the sidebar in the web interface and what happens when you go to eg `https://yournagiosserver.com/nagios/cgi-bin/extinfo.cgi?type=1&host=hostname1` ?

Comment: Also, are you saying that `hostname1` and `hostname2` are the same host? Normally in the host definition I would define the IP address in the `address` directive and the DNS name in the `alias` directive then in your services etc you can use `$HOSTADDRESS$` and `$HOSTALIAS$` depending on whether you need the IP or the name.

Comment: Okay, also just noticed you have essentially duplicated your HTTP service check by setting your host's `check_command` using `check_http` - this means it will tell you when the website is down, not the actual host (the default command is `check-host-alive` which is ping-based). So maybe the alerts you are seeing are for the service not the host - have you restarted Nagios since amending the config files?

Comment: - When I log into `https://nagiosserver.com/nagios/cgi-bin/extinfo.cgi?type=1&hostname1` I get a message saying that I do not have permission to view information for that host, I've tried to edit the CGI file but I am not sure where should make a change to view that info.
- Regarding your question about hostname1 and hostname2 both are different hosts I just wanted to let you know that I have hosts that resolve with a FQDN and some with IP addresses.
- When I deployed my server I was asked to check the http/https service but I can add the `check-host-alive` command, that's not a problem.

Comment: It looks like from your cgi.cfg that the adminnagios account has access to see all the hosts, you will get that permissions message even if the host doesn't exist so I think that maybe the Nagios service just needs restarted?

You don't need to specify `check-host-alive` as your `check_command`, if you just remove that directive from your host definition it will inherit it from the `generic-host` template.

Comment: - I tried restarting the service as well as the server completely but I still get the same error.
-Thanks for the advice on the `check_command`

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty confused then - can you post your contacts and templates config files to see if there's anything that might be causing it?

Comment: Sure, [templates.cfg](https://pastebin.com/dsSxkv23) and [contacts.cfg](https://pastebin.com/JtbwZ9Tc) I also have some contacts defined in different files like [this one](https://pastebin.com/C1CgvNbb)

Comment: I can see nagiosadmin user defined in contacts.cfg but not adminnagios which is the account you said you were logging into the web interface with (and is listed in cgi.cfg as having access to all the hosts).

Comment: I already fixed that, I did a full check of the users and contacts to be sure that there are no mistakes with the users

Comment: So where did you fix it and what account are you using?

Comment: I changed the cgi file restoring the original so every thing goes back to default values which are the ones in the contacts file, the account is nagios admin

Comment: So have you got `authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin` set in cgi.cfg, used `htpasswd` to set a password for nagiosadmin, verified the config, restarted Nagios and tried to check the host in the web interface?

Comment: Exactly, every user is nagiosadmin